# How to set listener for RecyclerView adapter?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, kotlin

On my `MainActivity` there is a `Button` and `RecyclerView` with adapter for `CheckedTextView`.

I want to enable `Button` when there is a click on `CheckedTextView`.

I was able to achieve it with setting `Button` context to `static` but it isn't good (memory leak etc.)

I tried to get the Button from `context` and enabling it in `simpleCheckedTextView.setOnClickListener`:

```
class AndroidDeviceAdapter(internal var context: Context, private val devices: Array<String>) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<AndroidDeviceAdapter.MyViewHolder>() {

    inner class MyViewHolder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
        ...
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MyViewHolder {
        ...
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {
        ...

        holder.simpleCheckedTextView.setOnClickListener {

        // Getting exception
        (context as Activity).findViewById<Button>(order_button).isEnabled = true
        }
    }
```

What is the best way do active the `Button`? Is it possible to set listener for `RecyclerView`?

Comment: Try making your adapter an inner class of the activity. That way you have access to the acitivity's button variable. Or after casting the context to your specific activity class use the dot "." operator to access the button. I am assuming your button is not in the recycler viewholder. Please share your activity code.

Comment: thanks, after changing to `(context as Activity).order_button.isEnabled = true` as you suggested I noticed that I passed `applicationContext` (application context) and not `this@OrderActivity` (activity context)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the following.

```
(context as OrderActivity).order_button.isEnabled = true
```

Assuming `order_button` is a variable in your `OrderActivity`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible. You can create a custom interface like this:

```java
public interface RecyclerViewClickListener {
    void recyclerViewItemClicked(View view, int position);
}
```

and inside your adapter:

```java
class AndroidDeviceAdapter(internal var context: Context, private val devices: Array<String>) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<AndroidDeviceAdapter.MyViewHolder>() {

   ...
   private RecyclerViewClickListener recyclerViewClickListener;
   ...

   public void setRecyclerViewClickListener(RecyclerViewClickListener recyclerViewClickListener)
   {
   this.recyclerViewClickListener=recyclerViewClickListener;
   }
   ...
```

And then add item click listener:

```java
 holder.simpleCheckedTextView.setOnClickListener {

        recyclerViewClickListener.recyclerViewItemClicked(holder.simpleCheckedTextView, getAdapterPosition());
        }
```

And then attach the listener in the activity where you want to perform a desired action.

Some of my snippets are in java style. somewhere combined with your kotlin code. Remember to sort please and adapt it to kotlin. Good coding

Answer (score 0):

You can define an interface inside `AndroidDeviceAdapter` like so:

```
interface MyCheckedTextListener {
    fun onCheckedTextClicked()
}
```

Instead of a `Context` parameter, the adapter's Constructor should take a `MyCheckedTextListener` parameter:

```
class AndroidDeviceAdapter(internal var checkedTextListener: MyCheckedTextListener,
     private val devices: Array<String>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<MyListAdapter.MyViewHolder>()
```

The `Activity` has to pass in an instance of `MyCheckedTextListener` when instantiating the adapter.

The adapter will notify the `Activity` via this instance:

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder?, position: Int) {
    holder?.simpleCheckedTextView?.setOnClickListener {
        checkedTextListener.onCheckedTextClicked()
    }
}
```

So the `Activity` can set the new `Button` state (and the `Button` can stay `private` and non `static`)